# Detecting ids of a widget after click

Tags: python, kivy

This should be simple but I could not find how to do it.
I want to access the id property of a label widget from python code created in Kivy to compare it to a string in the if clause.
Below is what I tried and could not succeed because self.ids is a dictionary.
How can I address it properly ? (Line "if self.ids == 'sample_label':")

Thanks in advance...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<MyGridLayout>

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size: root.width, root.height

        Clickable_Label:
            id:                 sample_label_1
            text:               "sample text 1"
            font_size:          18

        Clickable_Label:
            id:                 sample_label_2
            text:               "sample text 2"
            font_size:          18
""")

class MyGridLayout(Widget):
    pass

class Clickable_Label(Label):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if self.ids == 'sample_label':
                print( f"{self.text} is clicked")        

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: [`ids`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.ids) should be accessed on `root` level. Here you can access it via app's root or parent-chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ids` are dictionary of weak-ref to widgets. You can check membership of certain id by `in` operator as `some_id` `in` `some_root_ids`. Alternatively you can use `is` or `==` operator. But you have to access the ids dictionary on a `root` level of `kvlang`. Thus here you can access the id `sample_label_1` as,

Accessing `ids` from app's `root`,

```py
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if App.get_running_app().root.ids.sample_label_1 is self.proxy_ref:
                # Since id is just a weak reference.
                print( f"{self.text} is clicked")
```

Accessing the same widget by parent chain,

```py
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if self.parent.parent.ids.sample_label_1 is self.proxy_ref:
                # Since id is just a weak reference.
                print( f"{self.text} is clicked")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and kind answer. I just reversed if clause like; if self.proxy_ref is self.parent.parent.ids.sample_label_1: and implemented the rest as is.